# ¿Al usar la cláusula WHERE en MySQL se omiten los resultados nulos?

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo esta instrucción:

```
select distinct utm_source from website_sessions;
```

da como resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora, al querer omitir el renglon donde `utm_source='socialbook'`:

```
select distinct utm_source from website_sessions where utm_source<>'socialbook';
```

da este resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Omitiendo el resultado nulo aunque naturalmente es distinto a 'socialbook'.

¿`WHERE` descarta entonces los valores nulos automaticamente al hacer la selección? ¿O solo pasa en mysql?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

El problema es que al utilizar nulos, tenemos una logica de tres valores en vez de una lógica de dos valores. Estamos acostumbrados a decir que una condición resulta verdadera o falsa, pero con nulos tenemos la tercera opción que es 'desconocido'.

Por lo tanto, al hacer cualquier comparación con `NULL` obtendremos desconocido.
Ejemplos:

| Condición | Resultado |
| --- | --- |
| 1=1 | Verdadero |
| 1<>1 | Falso |
| 1=2 | Falso |
| 1<>2 | Falso |
| 1>2 | Falso |
| 1<2 | Verdadero |
| 1=NULL | Desconocido |
| 1<>NULL | Desconocido |
| 1>NULL | Desconocido |
| 1<NULL | Desconocido |

Al evaluar un `WHERE` solo se regresan las filas cuya condición regresa verdadero. Si quieres incluir los nulos, tienes que agregar una segunda condición unida mediante un OR.

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
      utm_source 
FROM  website_sessions 
WHERE utm_source <> 'socialbook'
OR utm_source IS NULL;
```

Answer (score 2):

Agrega a tu sentencia where

```
or campo is null
```

Para no omitir los nulos, es comportamiento estándar del lenguaje SQL.